# How can I import data from a website that requires a password to a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to automate the import, but how to write a custom function to fetches the data, and writes it to the spreadsheet.
this my app scrip
`function myFunction() {
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
//var queryString = Math.random;
var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("https://www.bybit.com/user/assets/order/derivatives/uniform-usdt/all-orders","table",1)';

sheetName.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);`your text`
}`
but how i set the id and password automatic update google sheet every hour to get data from the website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData() {
    var websiteUrl = 'YOUR_WEBSITE_URL';
    var loginCredentials = {
      'username': 'YOUR_USERNAME',
      'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
    };
    var requestOptions = {
      'method': 'post',
      'payload': loginCredentials
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(websiteUrl, requestOptions);
    var content = response.getContentText();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
  getData();
```

Hey, I really don't know what you are trying to do, so I have provided 2 ways to do the same but I would prefer that you refer to the Google Developers website while integrating it into your code. The above code will require some tries before it works fine.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

Follow these steps and hopefully, you will get your answer.

Comment: thanks for helping, I'm trying to get my order history from an authentication website call bybit and auto store all my history to google sheet. I will try the ways that you provided. I really appreciate your help